# Orchard CMS - Multiple Module Directories

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

Is it possible to configure multiple root Module directories in Orchard? My use case is that I want to keep my custom modules completely separate from the GIT clone of the orchard repository and to make it easier to pull down the latest orchard changes without having my customizations in the mix.

Comment: In visual studio I often create a new folder 'CustomModules', but physically it should be in the Modules directory on file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution for this problem that I often use is to store the modules in separate repositories and create hardlinks in the Orchard's Modules folder. For example, if you store your module's code in `C:\Modules\MyModule` and you want to use this with an Orchard enlistment in `C:\Orchard`, then you can create a hardlink (using `mklink` command in `cmd.exe`) in `C:\Orchard\src\Orchard.Web\Modules` which points to `C:\Modules\MyModule`. You can then use the module's code as if it was located directly in the `Modules` folder. You can even easily modify the code in the `Modules` folder and then commit the changes from `C:\Modules\MyModule`.

Here is an example of a script which creates such links:
https://github.com/Proligence/OrchardPs/blob/master/MapToOrchard.cmd

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported but most possibly will in the next major version of Orchard since there is an open PR for it: https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/pull/5973